# How can I merge two pandas dataframe rowwwise applying a rule?

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

How can I merge two pandas dataframe rowwwise? Both dataframes have n rows, and the result dataframe should contain 2n rows. The setup: The first row of dataframe A is the first, then the first row of dataframe B is the second, then the second row of A is the third etc. So the i_th row of A has to be the 2i-1_th row of the result, and the j_th row of B has to be the the 2j_th of the result.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), then [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last create default index, only necessary both index values has to be default `RangeIndex`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3,3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10, 19).reshape(3,3))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    0   1   2
0   0   1   2
1  10  11  12
2   3   4   5
3  13  14  15
4   6   7   8
5  16  17  18
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly what I looked for!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = # first df with columns
df2 = # second df with columns
output = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
for idx_1, idx_2 in range(df1.index, df2.index):
    output = output.append(df1.iloc[idx1])
    output = output.append(df2.iloc[idx2])
```

Hope this helps!